# Comparison of 0 to a string fails

Tags: php, function, methods

Update: 0 isn't using the default value, after testing it was the condition that was failing as suggested by the answers.

```
function test($value='A') {
   if ($value != 'A') {
     echo 'OK';
   }
   else {
     echo 'NOT OK';
   }
}

test(); // Outputs NOT OK
test('A'); // Outputs NOT OK
test(0); // Outputs NOT OK, Should output OK?
test('0'); // Outputs OK
test(null); // Outputs OK
test(false); // Outputs OK
```

This is kind of throwing one of my functions.  I was surprised to see only 0 does this and null works fine.  Does anyone know why PHP is interpreting 0 as the default value?

Comment: Actually, the strange thing here is echo $value is still 0.

Comment: That was the clue to the cause of the problem. It's not the defaulting, it's the comparing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, comparing a string `'A'` with a number `0` causes a change of the string to a number. In this case `'A'` gets converted to `0`, so of course `0 == 0`.

See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for details.

For completeness, the fix, from the same linked documentation is

> use strict comparison operators (===, !==)
>   comparison operators

Comment: Thanks, I realized that it wasn't using the default value, it was definitely the if condition that was causing the issue.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening so I can check even if my function uses an integer?

Comment: @Devon, See the other answers for that. I explained why it is a problem, but I do not think it's useful for me to repeat them since they already explained it so well.

Comment: Thanks, I saw their answers after I wrote that. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Devon, Updated for completeness, since you pointed it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your test to:

```
if ($value !== 'A') {
```

When you use `==` or `!=` to compare a number and a string, it coerces the string to a number. The string `'A'` converts to `0`, so they're equal.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I should have known that an identical comparison made more sense anyways considering it will always be the string A.

Comment: this is why some PHP and Javascript programmers _always_ use strict comparison operators.

Comment: Yes, that is probably a good idea.  I think the reason I got used to not using strict checks is because of inputs often using strings for numbers and causing issues but it is probably best to start making use of type casting with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

As you using loosely comparison operator PHP is trying to implicitly convert the 0 into the string. Use `!==` for strict comparison.

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BQE921)**.